# porque mi codigo duplica los registros mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un problema cuando hago esta consulta en mysql

```
select count(carne) TOTAL_ESTUDIANTES, profesor.nombre PROFESOR, cursos.asignatura CURSO
from profesor, cursos, matricula;
```

solo tengo 4 estudiantes pero cuando hago la consulta se duplica todo

ademas en la columna profesor deberian aparecer los demás nombres de los profesores pero solo sale uno al igual que en la columna de curso

Estos son los datos de cada una

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este el modelo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Edita tu pregunta incluyendo la definicion de tus tablas

Comment: Necesitas agrupar los datos

Comment: Como hago eso??

Comment: Por favor comparte una imagen de las 3 tablas y que se muestren los registros para poder ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Para que no te suceda eso utiliza el 
PERO ADEMÁS ALGO EN TU BASE ESTÁ MAL

```
select DISTINCT count(carne) TOTAL_ESTUDIANTES, profesor.nombre PROFESOR, cursos.asignatura CURSO
from profesor, cursos, matricula;
```

Comment: Me sigue pasando lo mismo :(